# Animate Scrollbar using Jquery and CSS direction property

Tags: css, jquery-animate, overflow

I have a div with a horizontal scroll bar. I am trying to animate the scrollbar when the screen loads to scroll all the way to the right and back again; for the purpose of showing the user what is available if they scroll.

With direction set to ltr in my CSS, the scroll is set all the way to the left hand side. With it set to rtl, it is set all the way to the right. This would suggest that implementing the below jquery animate code would achieve my goal. What is wrong with this approach and why does the code not do anything?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( "#divWithScroll" ).animate({ "direction": "rtl" }, "slow" );
$( "#divWithScroll" ).animate({ "direction": "ltr" }, "slow" );

});
```

CSS:

```
#divWithScroll{
position:absolute;
top:4em;
left:5%;
right:0px;
right:5%;
height:14em;
overflow-x:scroll;
overflow-y:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 90%;
direction:ltr;
}
```

Comment: `direction` isn't something you can animate on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide a code or fiddle.

From what I presume, I guess you should animate the left position of the div's content all the way to the left, then chain to animate it all the way to right back again.

sample:

```
$(content)
  .animate({"left": $(this).parent().width() - $(this).width()},"slow")
  .animate({"left": 0},"slow");
```